# GUI PGP / GnuPG application

Tags: macos, mail.app, software-recommendation, encryption, gpg

I encrypt all of my documents before storing them in the cloud with GnuPG. My wife needs access to the documents, but running `gpg -d foo.pdf.gpg` at the command line is annoying to her.

Does anyone know of a GUI app for PGP / GnuPG for MacOS X? It would be great to simply drag an encrypted file to it, be prompted for a private key passphrase, and then get the unencrypted file.

If nothing like this exists, I can probably whip one up in Clojure pretty easily, but I figured it was worth looking for one first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use gpgtools (https://gpgtools.org) it is got all the possible GPG tools you are probably going to need (they also have a gpg plugin for Apple Mail) and adds  Services for signing/encrypting/decrypting/etc. to the contextual menu (right-click->Services).

Comment: This tool seems cool. But it doesn't add anything to services automatically.

Comment: Something must have failed when you installed. I never had to do anything particular after installing the tools and when I right-click on a file or folder I get the full set of Services: validate, sign, encrypt, decrypt, etc. In OS X 10.7 to 10.10. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

Create a new service with automator so your wife can decrypt the file using the contextual menu in the Finder.

1. Create an Automator service
2. Service receives selected ***files or folders*** in ***Finder***
3. Add a ***Run Shell Script*** action.
4. Add your code: `gpg -d $1`
5. Save the service.
6. It is now available in the Finder via *Right click > Service > youServiceName*.

Comment: I accepted the GPG Tools answer because it was exactly what I asked, but thanks a lot for this tip! I actually did not know what automator services were, so this is really useful for the next time I need to script something. Very helpful!

Comment: That's the spirit of this site ;)